# I do not see logs in Dynatrace when Azure App Insight is enabled for Azure web app ( app services )

Tags: azure, appinsights, dynatrace

I do not see logs in Dynatrace when Azure App Insight is enabled for Azure web app ( app services )

1. I have enabled Azure App insight for 1 Azure web app ( MVC Application )
2. I have also added DynaTrace OneAgent extension in Azure web app
3. I observed that Dynatrace logs are not showing MVC/C# related traces
4. When I disable App insight from Azure portal it starts showing logs in Dynatrace
5. I raised ticket with Microsoft , MS informed that there is no issue at Azure App insight end and I need to connect with Dynatrace people

I tried disabled Azure app insight and dynatrace starts showing me APM logs

Comment: Actually it takes some time to reflect the traces to reflect.That is the reason you are unable to see the logs initially.

Comment: Now enable the App Insights and check whether you are getting the required logs or not.

Comment: @Harshitha : When telemtry was enabled from Code I did see logs in Dynatrace , but when App insight was enabled from Azure portal I waited for 1/2 days but did not see any log in Dyanatrace
But enabling telemetry from code has performance issues as per dynatrace

Comment: Have you configured any thing related to DynaTrace in code as well?

Comment: Could you please share the code which you have configured?

Comment: What is the framework of the WebApp ?

Comment: @Harshitha : 1) I have not done anything in the code with respect to Dynatrace
2).NET Framework version is 4.8 3) Used below code to log custom dimensions\properties in app insight from MVC\C# code
https://camerondwyer.com/2020/05/26/how-to-use-application-insights-custom-properties-in-azure-monitor-log-kusto-queries/

Comment: I have tried from my end. Can you please share the traces of DynaTrace which u are able to see later.

Comment: Iam able to see only the requests,but not the exceptions/dependencies.